# how to delete a record in rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to delete a record from a maodel but i got a strange behave:
when i delete a record form a non empty list it works perfectly but when it still just one record in that list and i try to delete it it generates this error:
in paniers_controller.rb:

```
def enlever
  @p = Panier.find(params[:id])
  @book = Book.where( id: @p.book_id).first
   if  @p
    @book= Book.update(@p.book_id, nbr_exemplaires: @p.quantity)
    @p= Panier.destroy(@p.id)
    redirect_to detail_path
   end

  end
```

in paniers/detail.html.erb

```
<tr><td>Reference du livre</td><td>prix du livre</td><td>Quantité</td><td>Services</td></tr>
  <% for p in @panier %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= p.book_id %></td><td><%= p.price%> $</td><td><%= p.quantity %></td><td><%= link_to 'enlever du panier', enlever_path(p), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td></tr>
      <% somme +=p.price * p.quantity %>
    <%end %>
```

in routes.rb

> get 'panier/enlever/:id' => 'paniers#enlever', as: :enlever

the error that I got is:

> Couldn't find Panier with 'id'=23

in this line:

> @p = Panier.find(params[:id])

but the record is deleted from the database in spite of the display of this error

Comment: if you want to destroy `@p`, just call `@p.destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to pluralize `@panier` in the view (also, check if you are initializing `@panier` with a list of panier, as opposed to a single panier) - something like:

```
# in paniers_controller.rb
def detail
  @panier = Panier.all
end

# in paniers/detail.html.erb
<% for p in @paniers %>
```